# $state.go() returns a resolved promise before transition to template

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

As the title says, im making a $state.go() and returns a resolved promise before making the transition to the desired template.. is this the normal behaviour of $state.go()?

Im mixing Q and $q promises so maybe it makes a problem altought im doing the $state.go() call inside $timeout() to guarantee it is executed under the angular digest cycle (i could also have used $q.when() but decided to use $timeout)

I want to wait until the new template is shown to execute a chaining code from the promise.

Something similar to this:

```
return Q.Promise.resolve()
.then(function(value){

    return $timeout( function() {})
    .then(function(value){
        return $state.go('app.propuestaRetake');
    });

}).then(function(value){    

    return $timeout( function() {
        $scope.$parent.$broadcast( "$ionicView.enter" );
    });

});
```

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do? This looks really convoluted.

Comment: (as the question says) I want to wait until the new template is shown to execute a chaining code from the promise. (not think its that convoluted? im using promise chaining and only adding $timeout extra layer for the angular digest cycle)

Comment: but you re doing all this in a controller ... why aren't you doing it in a service and pass the promise to controller in other state or run in onEnter?